# Play video on scroll but only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have this script that would play video when it reaches certain position ( on scroll ), but the problem is if you pause it and continue scrolling it would start playing again... I tried to do "one" on scroll function but that would not work since it would allow it to check for scroll only once which would be only on top of the screen...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

$('.video-panel').each(function(){
    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("lunar-video"); 



    if (imagePos < topOfWindow+$(window).height()/1.4) {
        $(".video-panel video").fadeIn();
        $("#lunar-video").prop('play');
        console.log('blejacki');
        // $(".video-panel").addClass('blejacki');
    }

});
```

});

Comment: edit the first line `$(window).scroll(function() {` with `$(window).one("scroll",function() {` it works

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the element and check if that class already exists.

```
if (imagePos < topOfWindow+$(window).height()/1.4) {
    $(".video-panel video").fadeIn();
    var $lv = $('#lunar-video');

    if(!$lv.hasClass('is-playing')){
        $lv.prop('play');
        $lv.addClass('is-playing');
    }

}
```